# Интерактивный ввод для запускаемого процесса

Tags: linux, shell, input

Сделал простой shell скрипт для переборки всех установленных пакетов и удаления ненужных:

```
#!/bin/sh

pkgs=`dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -f1 -d :`

echo "$pkgs" | while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    apt purge "$line"
done
```

Но когда shell интерпретатор вызывает `apt purge "$line"` apt останавливается с сообщением "Abort." по причине отсутствия интерактивного ввода:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  sysvinit-core
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  acl* systemd* systemd-sysv*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sysvinit-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 132 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

Как мне при запуске `apt purge "$line"` передать ввод в порожденный процес на момент его исполнения?

Comment: гуглите expect, он вас спасет

Comment: например: `apt -y ...`

Comment: 1. Хотелось бы обойтись без expect, если это конечно возможно. 2. `-y` не конает т.к. смысл скрипта как раз в том, чтоб можно было выбрать какие пакеты удалить, а какие оставить

Comment: для начала рекомендую все таки написать с помощью expect. Скорее всего все будет работать как нужно и на этом все и остановится.

Comment: Решил сделать подругому, сначала просто показывать зависимости удаляемые, а потом уже на самом shell задавать вопрос, а удалять ли и в зависимости от ответа запускать apt purge -y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

наиболее простой вариант — избавиться от переназначения *stdin* (происходящего, в частности, при запуске под-оболчки ввиду использования конвейера — `|`).

т.е., примерно так:

```
for line in $(dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1); do
  apt purge $line
done
```